# Ambiguous dependencies when I added a producer class

Tags: cdi

I was reading/testing the following tutorial about CDI: [[link]](https://code.google.com/p/jee6-cdi/wiki/DependencyInjectionAnIntroductoryTutorial_Part1).

And I got an exception when I added a producer class to the code.
Basically, there's an interface with a default implementation:

```
public interface ATMTransport {
    public void communicateWithBank(byte[] datapacket);
}


@Default
public class StandardAtmTransport implements ATMTransport {

    public void communicateWithBank(byte[] datapacket) {
        System.out.println("communicating with bank via Standard transport");
    }

}
```

Next, there's another class which injects the ATMTransport interface:

```
@Named("atm")
public class AutomatedTellerMachineImpl implements AutomatedTellerMachine {

    @Inject
    private ATMTransport transport;

    public void deposit(BigDecimal bd) {
        transport.communicateWithBank(null);
    }

}
```

Everything is OK so far. So in the section about 'producers', they show a new class:

```
public class TransportFactory {

    @Produces ATMTransport createTransport() {
        System.out.println("ATMTransport created with producer");
        return new StandardAtmTransport();
    }

}
```

Then, by adding the producer class I got this exception:

```
WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type ATMTransport with qualifiers @Default 
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private AutomatedTellerMachineImpl.transport at AutomatedTellerMachineImpl.transport(AutomatedTellerMachineImpl.java:0)

Possible dependencies: 
  - Managed Bean [class StandardAtmTransport] with qualifiers [@Default @Any],
  - Producer Method [ATMTransport] with qualifiers [@Any @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces TransportFactory.createTransport()]
```

I solved the problem by using qualifiers, but I really don't know why.

My question is, why does the producer class cause that exception? (They didn't mention anything about it on their tutorial).

I really need a little explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code you supplied, you ended up creating a default implementation of `ATMTransport` that is a managed bean.  The exception is caused by having both beans available with the same injection targets.  `@Default` is the qualifier added to all CDI beans.  Basically, there is no need for the producer method since the one provided by the class definition by itself is the same.

I guess the bigger question - what were you trying to do with the producer method?

Comment: It's for forcing the program to use the producer class to create new instances. Then does the producer method also have a hidden @default annotation?

Comment: Yes.  You can `@Veto` the class to get the behavior you want.